# oracle catch foreign key violation

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

First, I'm not a native speaker, sorry for my english.

I have a Oracle stored procedure. Inside this stored procedure , I have a  insert that would throws a ORA-02291 exception but my problem is that it doesn't throws any exceptinon.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE X.mi_procedure (
    xano         IN       NUMBER,   
    xprograma    IN       VARCHAR2,
   Xciclo IN VARCHAR2,
   yresultado   OUT      BOOLEAN,
   ycodope      OUT      VARCHAR2
)
IS

............



 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hola');

   INSERT INTO x.A
               (ano, cod_programa, centro, area_estudio, c_destino, REF,
                cursos, num_becas, num_meses, observaciones )
      SELECT ano, cod_programa, centro, area_estudio, c_destino, REF, cursos,
             num_becas, num_meses, observaciones
            FROM X.W
       WHERE cod_programa = xprograma AND ano = xano
       AND xciclo ='P;


DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error'||SQLCODE)
....................
 COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE;
end X.mi_procedure;
```

My problem is that Oracle says Procedure complete and doesn't throws any
ORA-02291 exception, and dmbsoput is :

hola
error0

however IF I a run that SQL in a SCRIPT ORACLE throws a 
ORA-02291 exception.

Could somebody explain this situation?

Thank you

Comment: Are you waiting exception when you compile stored procedure?

Comment: This usually means execution never actually gets to that block. I assume that's why you have the `put_line('hola')` right above it, to see if execution gets there. Does the procedure actually write that out to screen (or wherever you are directing output)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the values of the parameteres of the procedure.... Those parameters didn't give records for that sql.

Thank you at all.